# Processing Resque jobs using a remote worker

Tags: ruby, sinatra, resque

Currently whilst in development I am creating workers on the [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) server to process jobs. I now want to expand the pool of workers by having multiple servers acting as workers.

How can I setup a worker to pull jobs from a remote Resque server where the jobs are located?

(I use [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/))

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect your resque queues to remote instances of redis.

In order to connect to remote instances of redis with you should add the below in your resque conf: 
    Resque.redis = "redis://[host]:[port]"

you can take a look at the resque/redis connection relationship [here (on github)](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque.rb#L75-L88)

Also, it's most likely necessary that you'll need to maintain a copy of the application code on each machine where there is a worker running so that you can trigger resque via rake.

Comment: Thanks for the response - when you mention application code is that the 'job' code?